# boto3 s3 bucket tagging

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm getting access error while tagging a bucket. Please note that the role I'm using has s3 full access.
The code works fine till this point-

```
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
            s3_bucket = bucket
            s3_bucket_name = s3_bucket.name
            try:
                response = s3_client.get_bucket_tagging(Bucket=s3_bucket_name)
                print(response)
            except ClientError:
                print (s3_bucket_name, "does not have tags")
```

but after adding putTag code, it gives error even for GetBucketTagging operation.
This is my final code:

```
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
            s3_bucket = bucket
            s3_bucket_name = s3_bucket.name
            try:
                response = s3_client.get_bucket_tagging(Bucket=s3_bucket_name)
                print(response)
                
            except ClientError:
                print (s3_bucket_name, "does not have tags")
                bucket_tagging = s3.BucketTagging(s3_bucket_name)
                response = bucket_tagging.put(
                 Tagging={
                      'TagSet': [
                        {
                            'Key': 'pcs:name',
                            'Value': s3_bucket_name
                        },
                      ]
                    },
                )
```

The error I'm getting is-

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetBucketTagging operation: Access Denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tagging.py", line 91, in <module>
    tagging()
  File "tagging.py", line 71, in tagging
    'Value': s3_bucket_name
  File "/home/ec2-user/compass_backend/compass_backend/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/compass_backend/compass_backend/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
  File "/home/ec2-user/compass_backend/compass_backend/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 395, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/compass_backend/compass_backend/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 725, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutBucketTagging operation: Access Denied
```

am I passing the tag parameters wrong? Got this from Boto3 documentation itself

Comment: If you try [`aws s3 put-bucket-tagging`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-tagging.html) with the AWS CLI, using the same credentials, does it generate the same error?

Comment: no, I was able to tag from the console. There was some issue with try catch. Am using 'resourcegroupstaggingapi' now as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to catch the exception, however, this worked for me:

```
tagging_client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
     s3_bucket = bucket
     s3_bucket_name = s3_bucket.name
     bucket_tagging = s3.BucketTagging(s3_bucket_name)
     try:
        response = s3_client.get_bucket_tagging(Bucket=s3_bucket_name)
        a = response
     except ClientError:
        response = tagging_client.tag_resources(
        ResourceARNList=[
            "arn:aws:s3:::" + bucket.name
        ],
        Tags={
            'pcs:name': bucket.name
        }
      )
```

pls note that you'll need the additional "resource tagging" policy attached to your role.
Hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I took out the `try` sections and ran this version of your code:

```py
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket_tagging = s3_resource.BucketTagging('my-bucket-name')
response = bucket_tagging.put(
        Tagging={
            'TagSet': [
            {
                'Key': 'pcs:name',
                'Value': 'stackoverflow'
            },
            ]
        },
    )
```

It worked fine:

[[image: Amazon S3 bucket tags]

Therefore, there must be something else that is causing your request to fail. You might want to check AWS CloudTrail to see if there is a hint as to why the request was denied.

Answer (score 0):

"get_bucket_tagging" throws NoSuchTagSet when there are no tags. for testing create a tag first before run test or Catch the exception and create tags.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. That's what I;m doing right? creating that exception

Comment: Yes, that is what you are doing. However, it is generating an error on `bucket_tagging.put()`, which is not being handled by the code.